# SQL Injection new exploits

Tags: sql-injection

With reference to Blind SQL Injection as well as time-based and error messages techniques
is there any other trick an attacker can exploit?

I'm doing a bit of research in the field of Blind SQL Injection but I haven't been able to find any other approach which can be classified as Blind SQL Injection.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good explanation of the UNION-based blind SQL injection technique here:  http://gnahackteam.wordpress.com/2012/06/08/union-based-basic-sql-injection/

That was reportedly the technique used a few months ago to [hack Yahoo! Voices](http://www.informationweek.com/security/attacks/yahoo-hack-leaks-453000-voice-passwords/240003587).

Check out the book [SQL Injection Attacks and Defense](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1597499633) by Justin Clark et. al.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain variations of Blind-SQLi that are exploitable depending the DBMS.

Here's a good example of Blind-Boolean + Blacklist Bypass [DringenBlog](https://dringen.blogspot.com)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.